# Kali Linux --- Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: linux, dns, kali-linux

I am facing problems with internet, more specifically DNS in kali linux. I am running kali linux in VMware on a windows machine. After installing the kali  from https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-platforms when I opened up a shell and used

```
  ping google.com
```

It raised the following error

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have tried all kind of solutions found online. I have tried adding google's dns servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) to the `/etc/resolv.conf` file but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in Kali here as a VM inside VMware Workstation. Ping google.com works fine.

(1) Make sure your VM has NOT been set up as Host Only. Make sure the network connection is NAT or Bridge.  This is a common error.

(2) Make sure you made the VM from the main Kali ISO (not live or the prepackaged VM).

(3) If the above does not work, try repairing Kali.

sudo apt-get --fix-missing update  ...  to get missing updates.

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ...   to install new dependencies

Restart and test.

Make a new test Kali VM as described above (2) with a NAT connection and test Ping.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked fine! idk if it was some issue in the vm settings or what. But building from the main Kali ISO solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a working internet connection? You can try pinging an IP address instead of a domain thus circumventing name resolution. For example `ping 9.9.9.9`

Check if you have a valid IP address either in settings or in the terminal with the command
`ip a`